# How is calculating the unit tangent vector of a normal vector in 3d?

Tags: vector, java-3d, normals

This is easy to find the 2D unit tangent from the unit normal vector. Just make the x component of the unit tangent vector equal to the negative of the y component of the unit normal vector,
and make the y component of the unit tangent vector equal to the x component of the unit normal vector:

`ut =〈−uny, unx〉`

But how unit tangent from the unit normal vector is obtained in 3D with xyz components?

Comment: Don't you have a tangent plane instead of a tangent vector in 3D? Its much more complex but I'm not an expert. http://www.google.be/imgres?imgrefurl=http://meddic.jp/tangent_plane&tbnid=T7InlJmdhQF1uM:&docid=_TTdPX7Py_OUNM&h=595&w=721

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand your question correctly.
What I understand is that you have a vector (x,y,z) and you want to find the vectors perpendicular to this vector?

Vectors perpendicular to each other are vectors for which the dot product equals zero.
One is (-y,x,0) (if not both x and y are zero). Call it b1.
Another one is obtained computing the cross product of (x,y,z) and (-y,x,0). Call it b2.
The set of all vectors perpendicular to (x,y,z) is the set of linear combination of b1 and b2.